# Does mobile simulators work?Css Jquery on iPad

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, ipad-2

Hi everybody this is my jquery function to change font-size and other specific css values based on screen width.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var b=$(window).width();
var c=$(window).height();
$(document).ready(function() {
     get_font_size();
     set_sidebar();

});
function get_font_size()
{
var b=$(window).width();
var side_size=b*260/1440;
$("#alexa-widget img").css({"width":side_size});
$(".fb-like-box").attr("data-width",side_size); 
}
function set_sidebar()
{
var b=$(window).width();
var font_size=b*55/1440;
$("#my_tabs li").css({"font-size":font_size});
$("#justin input").attr("size",just_in);
}
</script>
```

I actually do a stupid math operation to find the font size and other css values for different screen sizes.What I do is I give the correct inputs for a screen width of 1440 say font size for 1440x768 is 20 px then for 1024x768 it would be 20x1024/1440.Though it is stupid it works fine and I tested with ipad and other android device using online simulators and also by changing user-agent setting in chrome and also in firefox. Indeed I was very happy but suddenly back to the start.I tested this in my ipad 2 and it failed miserably.

The css code of the required elements are:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
html
{
    height:100%;
}
#my_body {      

background: #f2f6f8;
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f2f6f8 0%, #d8e1e7 50%, #b5c6d0 51%, #e0eff9 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f2f6f8), color-stop(50%,#d8e1e7), color-stop(51%,#b5c6d0), color-stop(100%,#e0eff9));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #f2f6f8 0%,#d8e1e7 50%,#b5c6d0 51%,#e0eff9 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #f2f6f8 0%,#d8e1e7 50%,#b5c6d0 51%,#e0eff9 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #f2f6f8 0%,#d8e1e7 50%,#b5c6d0 51%,#e0eff9 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #f2f6f8 0%,#d8e1e7 50%,#b5c6d0 51%,#e0eff9 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f2f6f8', endColorstr='#e0eff9',GradientType=0 );
min-height:100%;
}
#wrapper { 
}
#content {
width:1150px;
margin-top:6%;
background: rgb(245,246,246);
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2Y1ZjZmNiIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjIxJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2RiZGNlMiIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjQ5JSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2I4YmFjNiIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjgwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2RkZGZlMyIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiNmNWY2ZjYiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(245,246,246,1) 0%, rgba(219,220,226,1) 21%, rgba(184,186,198,1) 49%, rgba(221,223,227,1) 80%, rgba(245,246,246,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(245,246,246,1)), color-stop(21%,rgba(219,220,226,1)), color-stop(49%,rgba(184,186,198,1)), color-stop(80%,rgba(221,223,227,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(245,246,246,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(245,246,246,1) 0%,rgba(219,220,226,1) 21%,rgba(184,186,198,1) 49%,rgba(221,223,227,1) 80%,rgba(245,246,246,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(245,246,246,1) 0%,rgba(219,220,226,1) 21%,rgba(184,186,198,1) 49%,rgba(221,223,227,1) 80%,rgba(245,246,246,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(245,246,246,1) 0%,rgba(219,220,226,1) 21%,rgba(184,186,198,1) 49%,rgba(221,223,227,1) 80%,rgba(245,246,246,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(245,246,246,1) 0%,rgba(219,220,226,1) 21%,rgba(184,186,198,1) 49%,rgba(221,223,227,1) 80%,rgba(245,246,246,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f5f6f6', endColorstr='#f5f6f6',GradientType=0 );

;
}
.headline_font {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 0px 1px #f29c93;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 0px 1px #f29c93;
    box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 0px 1px #f29c93;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #fe1a00), color-stop(1, #ce0100) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #fe1a00 5%, #ce0100 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fe1a00', endColorstr='#ce0100');
    background-color:#fe1a00;
    -moz-border-radius:12px;
    -webkit-border-radius:12px;
    border-radius:12px;
    border:1px solid #d83526;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:12px 40px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #b23e35;
    text-align:center;
}.headline_font:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ce0100), color-stop(1, #fe1a00) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ce0100 5%, #fe1a00 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ce0100', endColorstr='#fe1a00');
    background-color:#ce0100;
}.headline_font:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
#header
{
    height:240px;

}
@font-face {
    font-family:mypost-font;
    src:url('http://www.pnrenquiry.in/fonts/HelveticaNeue-Roman.otf');
    font-weight:lighter;

}
@font-face {
font-family:mytitle-font;
    src:url('http://www.pnrenquiry.in/fonts/Veneer.ttf');
}

#post_my_head
{
    font-family:mytitle-font;
    font-size:28px;
}
#post_my_head a
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
}
#post_my_content
{

    border-bottom:10px solid black;
    font-family:mypost-font;
    font-size:23px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:left;

}
#posted_date_time
{
    font-size:22px;
    font-weight:bolder;
    float:left;
}
#my_site_headline 
{
    width:100%;
    display:inline;

}
.headline_font {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 0px 1px #f29c93;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 0px 1px #f29c93;
    box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 0px 1px #f29c93;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #fe1a00), color-stop(1, #ce0100) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #fe1a00 5%, #ce0100 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fe1a00', endColorstr='#ce0100');
    background-color:#fe1a00;
    -moz-border-radius:12px;
    -webkit-border-radius:12px;
    border-radius:12px;
    border:1px solid #d83526;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:12px 40px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #b23e35;
    text-align:center;
}.headline_font:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ce0100), color-stop(1, #fe1a00) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ce0100 5%, #fe1a00 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ce0100', endColorstr='#fe1a00');
    background-color:#ce0100;
}.headline_font:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
/* This imageless css button was generated by CSSButtonGenerator.com */

#my_site_headline a
{
background: #ffffff;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #f1f1f1 50%, #e1e1e1 51%, #f6f6f6 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(50%,#f1f1f1), color-stop(51%,#e1e1e1), color-stop(100%,#f6f6f6));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 50%,#e1e1e1 51%,#f6f6f6 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 50%,#e1e1e1 51%,#f6f6f6 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 50%,#e1e1e1 51%,#f6f6f6 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 50%,#e1e1e1 51%,#f6f6f6 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#f6f6f6',GradientType=0 );




    text-decoration:none;
    border:2px #0033FF hidden;
    color:#000;
    font-size:26px;
    font-weight:bolder;
}


#nav
{
    position:fixed;
    width:82%;
    height:8%;  
/*  background: rgb(53,106,160);
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(53,106,160,1) 0%, rgba(53,106,160,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(53,106,160,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(53,106,160,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(53,106,160,1) 0%,rgba(53,106,160,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(53,106,160,1) 0%,rgba(53,106,160,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(53,106,160,1) 0%,rgba(53,106,160,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(53,106,160,1) 0%,rgba(53,106,160,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#356aa0', endColorstr='#356aa0',GradientType=0 );*/


}

@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
.button {
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 34px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align:center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 28px;
  -moz-border-radius: 28px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #666666;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #666666;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #666666;
  border: solid #2e2e2e 0px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#7abbfc), to(#3f9de6));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7abbfc, #3f9de6);
  -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr=#7abbfc, endColorStr=#3f9de6);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr=#7abbfc, endColorStr=#3f9de6);
  display:inline-block; /* IE is so silly */
}
.button:hover {
  background: #e62097;
}
#my_tabs 
{
    width:100%;
    list-style:none; 
    margin-left:-4%;

}


#my_tabs li
{
    float:left;
    display:inline;


}
#my_tabs li a
{
white-space:nowrap;
text-decoration:none;
/*   text-shadow: 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em #999999;
*/  color:#000;
font-family:mytitle-font;

padding-left:6%;
}

#my_post_link:link {

    text-decoration:none;
    color:#0145ec;
}
#my_post_link:visited
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#999;

}
#my_post_link:hover
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#F0F;
}

#tool-1 {
    font-family:mytitle-font;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:30px;
    color:#F00;
    width:960px;
    padding-top:15%;
    padding-left:5%;
}
#sidebar {
    right:0;
    width:18%;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:11%;

}
#twitter_follow
{
        padding-top:3px;

}
.fb-like-box {
    padding-top:3px;
    width:100%;
}
#alexa-widget
{
padding-top:3px;

}
#recent_posts
{
    border:2px #000000 solid;
        background: rgb(76,76,76); /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzRjNGM0YyIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEyJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzU5NTk1OSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjI1JSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzY2NjY2NiIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjM5JSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzQ3NDc0NyIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjUwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzJjMmMyYyIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjUxJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzAwMDAwMCIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjYwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzExMTExMSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9Ijc2JSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzJiMmIyYiIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjkxJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzFjMWMxYyIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiMxMzEzMTMiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%, rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 25%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%, rgba(44,44,44,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 60%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 76%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%, rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(76,76,76,1)), color-stop(12%,rgba(89,89,89,1)), color-stop(25%,rgba(102,102,102,1)), color-stop(39%,rgba(71,71,71,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(44,44,44,1)), color-stop(51%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(60%,rgba(17,17,17,1)), color-stop(76%,rgba(43,43,43,1)), color-stop(91%,rgba(28,28,28,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(19,19,19,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%,rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%,rgba(102,102,102,1) 25%,rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%,rgba(44,44,44,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%,rgba(17,17,17,1) 60%,rgba(43,43,43,1) 76%,rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%,rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%,rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%,rgba(102,102,102,1) 25%,rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%,rgba(44,44,44,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%,rgba(17,17,17,1) 60%,rgba(43,43,43,1) 76%,rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%,rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%,rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%,rgba(102,102,102,1) 25%,rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%,rgba(44,44,44,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%,rgba(17,17,17,1) 60%,rgba(43,43,43,1) 76%,rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%,rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%,rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%,rgba(102,102,102,1) 25%,rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%,rgba(44,44,44,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%,rgba(17,17,17,1) 60%,rgba(43,43,43,1) 76%,rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%,rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4c4c4c', endColorstr='#131313',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
}
#rec_post
{
    list-style:none;
    font-style:mytitle_font;
    font-size:22px;
    color:#F00;

}
#rec_post_li a
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:18px;



}
#my_post_links:link {

    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFF;
}
#my_post_links:visited
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#999;

}
#my_post_links:hover
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#F0F;
}
#my_links:link {

    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
}
#my_links:visited
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#999;

}
#my_links:hover
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#F0F;
}

#footer { 
height:200px;
text-align:center;
font-family:mypost-font;
font-size:35px;
color:#000;
}
#justin
{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:28px;
    font-weight:bolder;
    color:#F00;
    background:#000;
}
```

Sorry for posting a long code.Just see #content and #sidebar and #my_body.The sidebar and content fails.This is my screenshot on iPad 2.

[image: Ipad 2 screen shot]

This is my exact problem.I get this weird spaces in the right left out without being used.The font size re-sizing works perfect  but the width allocation fails.It works on my desktop,laptop and also in iPad and mobile simulators available online.Why does this happen?

I have few more questions.Does mobile simulators work?Are they reliable for UI testing purpose.If so why did they fail in my case?The online simulators I used were [link1](http://alexw.me/ipad2/) and [link2](http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/mini/).My website address is [link3](http://www.pnrenquiry.in).Please help me fix this.Thank You.

Comment: the only reliable simulators for iPhone and iPad devices that I know of are those installed along with XCode on a MAC OS machine... same goes for Android (their SDK have an emulator)... everything else will react very much according to which OS/browser combo you run it

Comment: @ZathrusWriter:Yup you are right.Just now faced the reality.Any ideas to fix my problem?

Comment: do you have a MAC? or a computer able to use run a virtual machine using MAC OS system? those are the only 2 solutions that worked for me

Comment: @ZathrusWriter: No I don't.I can't afford one.

Comment: if you can run VirtualBox and have an Intel motherboard that provides virtualization, you might be able to run a MAC OS inside it, then install XCode along with its simulators... AMD machine can also be used, but it has its own specifics and it's a very hardcore stuff sometimes to get it running

Comment: @ZathrusWriter:Thanks for the info.I would try that this weekend.I need some quick css or jquery fix to my problem right now.

Comment: How do you __legally__ install OS X on it? Doesn't Apple's EULA require it to be installed on a Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complex way to solve a simple thing!

The best way to scale things is to use the viewport settings: http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html

You can use this to scale the whole display up or down as needed.

You then typically use Media Queries ( http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/ ) to change the font-size or other properties as required.

If that isn't enough, you can use viewport relative units (rather than `px` or `em`, you use `vw`, `vh` and `vmin`) to size things.

In those examples, `1vm` = 1% of viewport width, `1vh` is for height, and `1vmin` is which ever is smallest.

Here's an example relating to your problem: http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/
These are supported in iOS 6.

Comment: @Brad:Yeah I know about media queries.I don't know how to use them and I find jQuery much easier than learning the tricky CSS.Anyways thanks for the info.Can you help me solve this in the jQuery way?

Comment: Learn media queries. It's like jQuery but easier, honestly!

Comment: Yeah just now started learning and it is really very easy.Thanks for the info.